# Including a .h file and directing .o files to a directory: Make

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to learn make files.

My directory Structure is

```
$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
   .
   |-bin
   |---exe
   |---obj
   |-build
   |-include
   |-lib
   |-make
   |-source
```

What I am trying to do is place my include file `conversion.h` in `include` folder, `all .c files` in `source`, `makefile` in `make`, compiled `all .o files` in `bin/obj` and `exe` in `/bin/exe`

I referred below posts:

[makefile include *.h file in other directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558881/makefile-include-h-file-in-other-directory)

[Using make to move .o files to a separate directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654548/using-make-to-move-o-files-to-a-separate-directory)

my makefile is:

```
VPATH= ./../source
OBJDIR= ./../bin/obj
EXEDIR= ./../bin/exe
#vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -I.
#INCLUDES= -I./../include

objects= binary.o hex.o octal.o

conversion: $(objects)
#       gcc -Wall -o conversion $(objects) -I.

binary.o: binary.c conversion.h
        gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

octal.o: octal.c conversion.h
        gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

hex.o: hex.c conversion.h
        gcc  $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@


clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*.o *.o *~ conversion
```

I am using cygwin. 
My questions are:

1) I am not able to include my `conversion.h` from location `./../include`
,`-I.` works fine if I copy `conversion.h` to `make` folder
-but as soon as I replace with `-I./../include` without any copy of `conversion.h` in `make` folder
I get below error

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'conversion.h', needed by 'binary.o'.  Stop.
```

2) My makefile does place all `.o` files to `/bin/obj` but when I try to use `vpath` as shown below (instead of using manual placement like -`-o $(OBJDIR)/$@`)

```
vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)
...
   $(OBJDIR)/binary.o: binary.c conversion.h
             gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
...
...
```

doing above replacement for all .o rules,does not place `all .o files` to `bin/obj` directory

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And to answer your second question, don't use `vpath` to find object, use `vpath` to find sources as noted by Paul's third rule of Makefiles (http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558881/makefile-include-h-file-in-other-directory  I am referring this link.. This way of including `.h and .o` did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to be explicit about the locations of the .h file, the .c files, the .o files, and the executable when you define the targets and their dependencies.

```
VPATH= ./../source
INCLUDEDIR= ./../include
OBJDIR= ./../bin/obj
EXEDIR= ./../bin/exe
#vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)
INCLUDES= -I./../include
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -I. $(INCLUDES)

objects= $(OBJDIR)/binary.o $(OBJDIR)/hex.o $(OBJDIR)/octal.o

$(EXEDIR)/conversion: $(objects)
#       gcc -Wall -o conversion $(objects) -I.

$(OBJDIR)/binary.o: $(VPATH)/binary.c $(INCLUDEDIR)/conversion.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/octal.o: $(VPATH)/octal.c $(INCLUDEDIR)/conversion.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/hex.o: $(VPATH)/hex.c $(INCLUDEDIR)/conversion.h
    gcc  $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*.o *.o *~ $(EXEDIR)/conversion
```

Comment: You'll need to add `-I$(INCLUDEDIR)` to CFLAGS as well.

Comment: How to use `vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)` then ? If we are explicitly mentioning path for each `.o`

Comment: You can remove `$(VPATH)/` from the dependency list. That should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Since your header files are in a separate directory, `make` cannot locate them.  Since it can't locate them, it tries to build them by looking for a target rule.  Since it cant find a target, you get the error listed in your question.

The `-I./../includes` only affects the compiler's include search path.  It does not affect how `make` looks for include.

If you want `make` to search for your header files you will need to add a `vpath` for the headers.  You will likely get the same error for the source files since they are in a separate directory as well.  Thus, you will need to add a `vpath` for the source files as well.

To get your original to work with `vpath` as opposed to explicit locations, try the following:

```
VPATH= ./../source
OBJDIR= ./../bin/obj
EXEDIR= ./../bin/exe
INCLUDES= -I./../include
vpath %.c $(VPATH)
vpath %.h $(INCLUDES)
vpath %.o $(OBJDIR)
CFLAGS= -Wall -c -I. $(INCLUDES)
```

As noted in my comment and the comments for your referenced question, it is not recommended to use `vpath` to locate object files.